# Sending values from one sheet to another sheet in Excel using Autohotkey

Tags: autohotkey

I have two sheets- sheet1 and sheet2. In sheet1 there are account no of the customers in column A and the name of customers in column B, as shown in sheet1 in the following example.

Now I want that when I type the account no of the customer in column A of sheet2, it should automatically send the name of the customer in front of the account no in column B.

You can see in the following example that in A2 cell of sheet2 I only type the account no of the customer i.e. ‘851’ now it should automatically send the name of the customer i.e. ‘brown’ in cell B2.

Similarly in cell A3 I only type the account no of the customer i.e. ‘707’ and it should send the name of the customer in B3 cell i.e. ‘thomas’. And so on...

Kindly help me as I have a very large list of account no of the customers and their names...

Please tell me how to use Autohotkey to do this task.

SHEET1
   A                                            B
ACCOUNT NO OF THE CUSTOMERS          NAME OF THE CUSTOMERS
475                                         smith
625                                         johnson
369                                         williams
851                                         brown
102                                         davis
305                                         millar
869                                         wilson
960                                         anderson
407                                         thomas
630                                         martin

SHEET2
    A                                         B
ACCOUNT NO OF THE CUSTOMERS             NAME OF THE CUSTOMERS
851                                         brown
407                                         thomas
305                                         millar

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want a VLOOKUP formula in column B of Sheet2.

Here's [a good site](http://spreadsheets.about.com/od/excelfunctions/ss/vlookup.htm) for learning about VLOOKUP.

Here's a screenshot demonstrating what you are requesting. In the left sheet (sheet1), I have a range of numbers and letters. In the right sheet (sheet2), I type the number in column A and column B populates with the associated letter.

[image]